# Gerrit code review: is there a way to filter out (exclude) specific files from the review?

Tags: gerrit

Assume I received a gerrit review with following structure, and I only want to see (review) the files under `Folder A`. Does the GUI support that?

```
root dir
  |
  |--> Folder A
  |
  |--> Folder B
  |
  |--> Folder C
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't have any specific feature related to that.